# Demmler-Reinsch basis for smoothing splines

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-smoothing, splines, smoothing, basis-function

I have seen some papers about using the so-called Demmler-Reinsch basis for smoothing spline because it is a basis for ***natural spline*** space and also ***Sobolev*** space. For example, these papers:

[A unified framework for spline estimators](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06318),

[Adaptive empirical Bayesian smoothing splines](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.6860),

and

[Adaptive Non-parametric Estimation of Mean and Autocovariance in Regression with Dependent Errors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.06948).

I found some lecture notes like this [note](http://web.math.ku.dk/~richard/courses/statlearn2009/lecture6aScreen.pdf) have also described this basis. I want to know can I use this basis for other non-parametric problems like the Gaussian process when we project the inputs into the feature space? (e.g. Section 2.1.2 in this book: ***[Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/)***). In all of the references, it was defined as a nice tool in the smoothing spline method. Since smoothing splines are a specific form of Gaussian process, is it possible to apply this basis as a basis of functions in the Gaussian process?

Comment: Make a more complete question by linking to the papers, please.

Comment: @Carl Thanks for your comment. I edited the question by adding some references.